# Integral Convergence test for Sum

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to implement the integral test for sum convergence on the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}\cdot e^{\sqrt{n}}}
$$

I've proved that the function $f:[1,\infty]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}\cdot e^{\sqrt{x}}}$ is monotonically descending and positive for all $x\ge 1$,

and also that the improper integral
$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}\cdot e^{\sqrt{x}}}dx$ converges,  therefor the sum  stated above is convergent.

However, according to an online calculator, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}\cdot e^{\sqrt{n}}}$ is divergent, which makes no sense to me.

(said calculator only provides further information for money, as a student, I cannot afford such luxuries.)

Currently I am uncertain in my solution.

Any assistance/guidance is happily accepted!

Comment: The sum converges, hint : $e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $0$ faster than $n^k$ for all $k\geqslant 1$.

Comment: You likely entered the expression in incorrectly. (Your argument is correct.)

Comment: I dont know what online calculator you have used, but for example WolframAlpha says that it converges. Also you can try another convergence test to prove it

Comment: What online calculator did you use?

Comment: I've used SymboLab's online calculator for sum convergence.

Probably a bug on their side, other calculators came to the conclusion that the sum is indeed convergent.

Comment: Very strange; it correctly says $\sum{\sqrt n\over e^{\sqrt n}}$ converges.

Comment: It also gives the correct result if you write the summand as $n^{-1/2}e^{-\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Tell me I'm not blind, please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For any $ X>1$,

$$F(X)=\int_1^X\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}}$$
$$=\Big[-e^{-\sqrt{x}}\Big]_1^X$$

$$=e^{-1}-e^{-\sqrt{X}}$$

$$\lim_{X\to\infty}F(X)=e^{-1}$$

the integrale is surely convergent.